# Python sorted not sorting Counter output properly

Tags: python, sorting, tuples, counter

I am trying to sort out min page load time and max page load time from Apache access log file. After parsing the log file and sorting using sorted I am seeing weird sorting.

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

from collections import Counter 
import re
import sys

logfile = sys.argv[1]

def abcd(match):
    clean_log = []

    for line in open(logfile):
        try:
            if re.findall(match, line):
                clean_log.append(re.findall(match, line))
        except ValueError:
            pass
    return(clean_log)


serve_time = "\d+$"

print(sorted(Counter(map(tuple, abcd(serve_time))).most_common(), key = lambda i: (i[0])))
```

The above code sorting thousandths and only then sorting hundreds:

```
$ ./log-parser.py access.log
[(('1660',), 1), (('1971',), 1), (('2020',), 1), (('2358',), 1), (('2384',), 1), (('2523',), 1), (('2976',), 1), (('3939',), 1), (('455',), 1), (('677',), 1)]
```

As you see 455 and 677 are at the end, but if you look separately at thousandths and hundreds sorting is going correctly.

Can someone shed light into this please?

BTW, if I don't use map to tuple I am getting "TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'" error for "Counter", thus need to work with tuple. Sorting using method below is the same story:

```
    print(sorted(abcd(serve_time)))

[['1660'], ['1971'], ['2020'], ['2358'], ['2384'], ['2523'], ['2976'], ['3939'], ['455'], ['677']]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's sorting by string and not by number

and '3' > '2'

if you want to sort by number change your lambda to:

```
key=lambda i: int(i[0])
```

Comment: glad I could help, please mark it "answered" if it resolved your problem.

Answer (score 2):

They are strings. String equality is determined by the first character first as strings are sequences. The first character is a digit here. String with the number 6 as the first character is the last one in that order so it's sorting strings properly.

To fix it you just need to dump the value to int.

> Sequence objects typically may be compared to other objects with the same sequence type. The comparison uses lexicographical ordering: first the first two items are compared, and if they differ this determines the outcome of the comparison; if they are equal, the next two items are compared, and so on, until either sequence is exhausted. If two items to be compared are themselves sequences of the same type, the lexicographical comparison is carried out recursively. If all items of two sequences compare equal, the sequences are considered equal. If one sequence is an initial sub-sequence of the other, the shorter sequence is the smaller (lesser) one. Lexicographical ordering for strings uses the Unicode code point number to order individual characters. Some examples of comparisons between sequences of the same type:

https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#comparing-sequences-and-other-types